# Are Fluvial and River Terraces the same?

Tags: geology, rivers, geomorphology, lakes

I study about fluvial terraces. However, resources related to this topic are limited. When I searched fluvial terraces in geomorphology books, I cannot find anything, but I find river terraces. My English is not good, so I am not sure fluvial terraces and river terraces are same. Do these two terms represent the same topic, please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, the word [fluvial](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluvial) comes from the Latin word for river.

[Fluvial processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluvial_processes) are processes associated with rivers or streams and the deposits and forms created by them.

[River terraces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_terraces_(tectonic%E2%80%93climatic_interaction)) and [fluvial terraces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluvial_terrace) are the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much @Fred.